# Join with case statement when returning values from table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need this query to return two values from the REPORT table, SUBJECT and ID_NUM.

Subject is selected as normal, but ID_NUM should only be selected if the SECRET is set to N in table IMS.

I would normally do

```
join on REPORT.ID_NUM = IMS.IR_ID_NUM
```

But in the SELECT statement Im unsure how to do this during the SELECT part before I have specified the WHERE table.

```
SELECT SUBJECT,

--Check if secret before selecting values
--Secret column is in IMS table, value i want selected is in REPORT
CASE

    WHEN (SECRET = 'N') THEN ID_NUM     
    ELSE 'SECRET' END                                                                                
    AS 'ID_NUM  ',

FROM REPORT

    INNER JOIN IMS ON ID_NUM = IR_ID_NUM
    INNER JOIN IR_SUBJECT ON IR_ID_NUM = SUB_ID_NUM
```

Comment: What is it outputting now?

Comment: If ID_NUM is not a char or varchar you will need to use cast or convert since you are using string in the else case

Comment: then what's the result of your query now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different clauses of a SQL statement are (logically) executed in a certain order:

```sql
SELECT ...        // 5.
  FROM ...        // 1.
  JOIN ... ON ...
 WHERE ...        // 2.
 GROUP BY ...     // 3.
HAVING ...        // 4.
 ORDER BY ...     // 6.
```

Taking them in order:

1. All records are select `FROM` the tables, applying any joins `ON` conditions, and cross-joining tables separated by comma (`,`).
2. Records are filtered according to `WHERE` clause.
3. Records are `GROUP`'ed.
4. Grouped values are filtered according to `HAVING` clause.
5. Result values are `SELECT`'d. Columns from all tables listed in `FROM` clause are available, including `JOIN` tables.
6. Result rows are `ORDER`'ed. You can even order by a calculated result value.

So, your `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` clause can access both `SECRET` and `ID_NUM` without problem.

Note: It is recommended to always qualify column names when more than one table is given. It is required if column name is ambiguous (more than one table has column of same name), but you should do it even for non-ambiguous column names, as documentation for other people (and yourself) reading the SQL statement later.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great explanation